# Which extension is this used in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

Hey recently I just familiar with this extension but don't know it's name in vs code.
So in the picture given below check that there is a blue vertical line in the left of the selected code. Which extension is this[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is not theme specific -- It is a VSCode indicator of lines added to a file before it has been saved.